# Permitir solo la entrada de un <input type="number">

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Busque por tutos y no encontre nada, alguien paso por esto ?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        Valor:<br />
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txtvalor" value="0" Placeholder="Valor" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        Porcentaje:<br />
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txtporcentaje" value="0" placeholder="Porcentaje" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="vertical-align:bottom">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btngravadescuentos"> Cargar </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Al presionar **cargar** me tiene que validar si esta lleno uno solo,
si ninguno esta lleno me hace un **required** 
y si quiero llenar en los dos no me tiene que dejar llenar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

acepto cualquier sugerencia

**LLEGO ESTO**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1.- Seleccione Descuento esta por defecto y es un valor vacio
    - un required si presiono el boton de "Seleccione un descuento"

2.- un required si presiona el boton y no esta lleno los campos de porcentaje o 
    valor

3.- un mensaje (no alert) que diga solo llene un campo "valor o porcentaje"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿qué tal si pruebas usar jquery y cambias la lógica a que si el usuario quiere ingresar en más de un textbox se limpie el otro?  y con respecto a que sea requerido también puedes usar jquery y su plugin validate [plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            Valor:<br />
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txtvalor" value="0" Placeholder="Valor" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            Porcentaje:<br />
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txtporcentaje" value="0" placeholder="Porcentaje" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="vertical-align:bottom">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btngravadescuentos"> Cargar </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#txtvalor").on("keypress", function() {
            $("#txtporcentaje").val("");
        });
        $("#txtporcentaje").on("keypress", function() {
            $("#txtvalor").val("");
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

El script sería algo así:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btngravadescuentos").on('click',function(){
                let campo1=$("#btngravadescuentos").val();
                let campo2=$("#btngravadescuentos").val();
                if(campo1.length<1 && campo2.length<1){
                    //Acciones para vallidar
                    alert("Debe llenar algún campo");
                }else if(campo1.length>0 && campo2.length>0){
                    //Acciones para vallidar
                    alert("solo debe llenar un campo");
                }else{
                   //Acción por defecto
                }
            });
        });

        </script>
```

Comment: podrias agregar una explicacin y luego la respuesta?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes deshabilitar el otro input cuando se rellena uno de ellos.

En el botón simplemente tienes que comprobar que no estén los dos vacíos:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#txtporcentaje').change(function(){
    var tieneValor = $(this).val() !== '';
    $('#txtvalor').prop('disabled', tieneValor);
  });
  $('#txtvalor').change(function(){
    var tieneValor = $(this).val() !== '';
    $('#txtporcentaje').prop('disabled', tieneValor);
  });
  $('#btngravadescuentos').click(function(){
    return $('#txtvalor').val() !== ''
      || $('#txtporcentaje').val() !== '';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        Valor:<br />
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txtvalor" Placeholder="Valor" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        Porcentaje:<br />
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txtporcentaje" placeholder="Porcentaje" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="vertical-align:bottom">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btngravadescuentos"> Cargar </button>
    </div>
</div>
```